# How do I set the type of a Pin that I want as an `Output` in `arduino_hal`?

Tags: rust, arduino-uno

I am trying to code a driver for an LCM1602C LCD display in Rust for the Arduino Uno using `arduino_hal` because I have not found a library for it. What I have thus far is:

```
use arduino_hal::Peripherals;
use arduino_hal::port::Pin;
use arduino_hal::port::mode::Output;

struct Lcd {
    rs: Pin<Output, PD1>,
    en: Pin<Output, PD2>,
    d4: Pin<Output, PD4>,
    d5: Pin<Output, PD5>,
    d6: Pin<Output, PD6>,
    d7: Pin<Output, PD7>,
}

impl Lcd {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let dp = arduino_hal::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
        let pins = arduino_hal::pins!(dp);

        let rs = pins.d1.into_output();
        let en = pins.d2.into_output();
        let d4 = pins.d4.into_output();
        let d5 = pins.d5.into_output();
        let d6 = pins.d6.into_output();
        let d7 = pins.d7.into_output();
                                
        Lcd {
            rs: rs,
            en: en,
            d4: d4,
            d5: d5,
            d6: d6,
            d7: d7,
        }
    }

    pub fn init(&mut self) {
        // Initialization sequence
        for _ in 0..3 {
            self.write_nibble(0x03, false);
            arduino_hal::delay_ms(5);
        }
        self.write_nibble(0x02, false);
        arduino_hal::delay_ms(5);

        // Function set
        self.write_command(0x28);
        arduino_hal::delay_ms(5);

        // Display on/off control
        self.write_command(0x0C);
        arduino_hal::delay_ms(5);

        // Clear display
        self.write_command(0x01);
        arduino_hal::delay_ms(5);

        // Entry mode set
        self.write_command(0x06);
        arduino_hal::delay_ms(5);
    }

    pub fn write_command(&mut self, command: u8) {
        self.write_byte(command, false);
    }

    pub fn write_string(&mut self, s: &str) {
        for c in s.chars() {
            self.write_byte(c as u8, true);
            arduino_hal::delay_ms(1);
        }
    }

    pub fn write_byte(&mut self, byte: u8, rs: bool) {
        self.rs.set_high();
        if rs {
            self.rs.set_high();
        } else {
            self.rs.set_low();
        }
        self.write_nibble(byte >> 4, rs);
        self.write_nibble(byte & 0x0F, rs);
    }

    fn write_nibble(&mut self, nibble: u8, rs: bool) {
        if (nibble & 0x01) != 0 {
            self.d4.set_high();
        } else {
            self.d4.set_low();
        }
        if (nibble & 0x02) != 0 {
            self.d5.set_high();
        } else {
            self.d5.set_low();
        }
        if (nibble & 0x04) != 0 {
            self.d6.set_high();
        } else {
            self.d6.set_low();
        }
        if (nibble & 0x08) != 0 {
            self.d7.set_high();
        } else {
            self.d7.set_low();
        }
        self.enable();
    }

    fn enable(&mut self) {
        self.en.set_high();
        arduino_hal::delay_us(1);
        self.en.set_low();
        arduino_hal::delay_us(1);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that this is Not how one should set up the pins in the `Lcd` struct, even though it looks like the [documentation](https://rahix.github.io/avr-hal/arduino_hal/port/type.Pin.html) (I believe). The error I get looks like this:

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `PD1` in this scope
 --> src/lcd.rs:7:21
  |
6 | struct Lcd {
  |           - help: you might be missing a type parameter: `<PD1>`
7 |                 rs: Pin<Output, PD1>,
  |                                 ^^^ not found in this scope
```

I have also tried to not have the `Pin` set but only have `Pin<Output>` on every pin, but then I get

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lcd.rs:28:17
   |
28 |             rs: rs,
   |                 ^^ expected struct `Dynamic`, found struct `PD1`
   |
   = note: expected struct `avr_hal_generic::port::Pin<_, Dynamic>`
              found struct `avr_hal_generic::port::Pin<_, PD1>`
```

which seems to contradict the last error message.

Do anyone know what is happening?

Edit:
To help you reproduce the error you can follow the setup at [avr-hal](https://github.com/Rahix/avr-hal) and generate a project using `cargo generate --git https://github.com/Rahix/avr-hal-template.git`. I am on an Arch Linux box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing if the driver itself is correct yet because I have not had time to test it, I did find a way to fix the compilation error. Apparently what I had to do is to use `.downgrade()` on each pin and then use `Output` as the type. Also made the struct public so I can use it in my application. Combined it looks like this:

```
use arduino_hal::port::{mode, Pin};

pub struct Lcd {
    rs: Pin<mode::Output>,
    en: Pin<mode::Output>,
    d4: Pin<mode::Output>,
    d5: Pin<mode::Output>,
    d6: Pin<mode::Output>,
    d7: Pin<mode::Output>,
}

impl Lcd {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let dp = arduino_hal::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
        let pins = arduino_hal::pins!(dp);

        let rs = pins.d1.into_output().downgrade();
        let en = pins.d2.into_output().downgrade();
        let d4 = pins.d4.into_output().downgrade();
        let d5 = pins.d5.into_output().downgrade();
        let d6 = pins.d6.into_output().downgrade();
        let d7 = pins.d7.into_output().downgrade();
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```